# Factory girl : validates associated leads to undefined method valid? for nil:Nilclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have model `Student`, which `has_one` `:account`.

All input-related data is stored inside of account. Student model just plays it's role when it comes to relations (some other models belong to student).

Problem: I can't test it with factory girl.

```
 factory :student do
   end
```

As I can't define anything besides it.

What I get on every attempt of `@student = FactoryGirl.create(:student)`:

```
undefined method `valid?' for nil:NilClass
```

Any fixes?

**Additional code**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :account_holder, :polymorphic => true
...
end

factory :account do
sequence :name do |n|
  "Name#{n}"
end
  sequence :surname do |n|
    "Surname#{n}"
  end
  sequence :phone do |n|
    "8911222332#{n}"
  end
  sequence :email do |n|
    "somemail#{n}@mail.ru"
  end
  student
end
```

**Source of issue**

Student has:

```
validates_associated_extended :account
```

which is basically usual `validate` but with error extraction for parent model.

So when FactoryGirl attempts to create student, it validates account, which is `nil`.

I tried this:

```
before(:create) {|student| build(:account, :account_holder =>student )}
```

in `student factory`, while in `account factory`:

```
association :account_holder, :factory=>:student
```

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: did you put the factory where it belongs: inside a FactoryGirl.define block?. Now, what i seems here does not seem to be a problem with FactoryGirl. It seems that either you are not building your model right and that some validations you set on the model crash because of some missing association. More code would help.

Comment: @muichkine, could it be related with that account is polymorphic?

Comment: FactoryGirl works just fine with polymorphic associations.I see nowhere in your factory where you set the account_holder relation. I would really take a look at your validations for the source of your problem. What you can also try is FactoryGirl.build(:student).valid? then debug if it is not.

Comment: @muichkine, I don't think that source of problem is validation, as it doesn't pass no validation, it says it can't validate nil, so my factory is nil for some reason. May be I declared it wrong? Should I specify that account belongs to account holder in factory?

Comment: Can you show the `Student` model?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn well I found the source of problem (updated) but don't figured out solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
factory :student do
  after :build do |student|
     student.account << create(:account, :account_holder => student) if student.account_holder.nil?
  end
end
```

This allows you to have both a valid student and to specify an account if you want to force one.
I think latest versions of FactoryGirl even allow that to be written as lazy attribute syntax:

```
factory :student do
  account { create(:account) }
end
```

Comment: already figured out, but it is quite the same what I've done, so accepted)